# csv file to an object, c++

Tags: javascript, c++, csv

I've got a simple CSV file:

```
name,surname
Joe,Moe
Bob,Rob
```

In JavaScript I would simply create an array of objects in the following way:

```
// let's assume the csv file is valid and it was already processed
var csv = ["name", "surname", "Joe", "Moe", "Bob", "Rob"],
    ret = [],
    i, ilen, j, o,
    cols = 2;        

for (i = cols, ilen = csv.length; i < ilen; i += cols) {
    o = {};
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j += 1) {
       o[csv[j]] = csv[i + j];
    }
    ret.push(o);
}

console.log(ret); // [{name: "Joe", surname: "Moe"}, {name: "Bob", surname: "Rob"}]
```

I'd like to create a vector filled with objects (instances of a class). The class would need to be generated during run-time, the csv file might change.

Could you guide how to achieve this in c++?

Comment: That's not a CSV file, the items are separated by whitespace. Nonetheless, the general approach should be to read the file line by line, splitting them into whitespace-separated columns. See [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to get a line from a file and the question [Splitting a string by whitespace in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275135/splitting-a-string-by-whitespace-in-c) for how to split that into items.

Comment: I know how to split a string, could you let me know how can I create a class dynamically while the program is running? Please assume that the csv input might change

Comment: Look up the `new` operator to allocate objects *dynamically* which means during run-time in the dynamic memory area.

Comment: Ok, but the class would need to exist first and in my case I'd like to create the class during run-time.

Comment: No need to manually generate objects in this case, though - you could have a vector<string>, have a local string, and simply store the string multiple times. Changing your string after storing it will not change strings you've stored because the objects in the vector are by-value, so you can change + store as many times as needed. It is dynamic behind the scenes.

Comment: I'd like to build something more complex on top of it, it'll be easier for me to take an object oriented approach and I'd like to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has no concept of a dynamic type that can be constructed at run-time. You'll have to use collections, like `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`, which could store a row of (name, value) pairs.